# Displaying data from the DB using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hey guys I am having trouble displaying data from my DB in an orderly way.

I am supposed to display the data starting from the heading then the information below. I am using `foreach()` loop and its displaying all the headings first then the information below.It actualy does not have any error the problem is that it is displaying the titles eg book title together and then all the paragraphs together but i want it to display the title then a paragraph another tiltle then its coresponding paragraph.

I am using these lines to display:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $dat): ?>
<h3 ><?php echo htmlspecialchars($dat, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> </h3> 
<?php  endforeach; ?>

<?php foreach ($par as $parag): ?>
<p >
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($parag, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
</p>
<?php endforeach; ?>  

my image.php this

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bcss.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","roots");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("blog", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM data");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // display image
    echo "<img src='".$row['image']."' />";
}
mysql_close($con);
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your problem? what kind of trouble are you having ? be precise and accurate.

Comment: I can't seem to visualize what the output would look like. Any visual aids would be helpful. Or how do you want it to be displayed (in layout)

Comment: Why are you `echo`ing stuff before your `<html>` tag ?

Comment: What is `$row['image']`? A link to the image?

Comment: Don't use mysql_*, it's ancient.

Comment: show how you want the output look like

Comment: what are the headers and paragraphs here? also where you want the images to be displayed

Comment: if you want more columns displayed than `image`, you have to select more columns. Or use wildcard all columns: `SELECT * FROM....`

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,, I am assuming that u have same no.of headings and para ,, i didnt checked the code :)

```
<?php foreach ($data as $key=>$value): ?>
<h3 ><?php echo htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> </h3> 
<p >
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($par[$key], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
</p>

<?php  endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Dont Forget to make this as Accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

you have created 2 foreach.
1 for heading.
and
2 for information.

so u geting all title first and then all information.

so u should use only one loop for both.

try this

```
<?php foreach ($data as $dat): ?>

    <!-- heading display -->
    <h3 ><?php echo htmlspecialchars($dat, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></h3> 

    <!-- description display -->
    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($parag, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```